# Conformal mapping to the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

I am studying for a prelim and I dont know how to do this:
Find a conformal mapping that maps the set $\{z\in\mathbb{C}: |z|>1, Re(z)>0\}$ to the unit disk.

I tried using $z^2$ and $1/z$ but I don't think that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct $z^2$ followed by $1/z$ is a good try, but it is Wrong! It does not respect the boundary requirement.

Hint: the map 
\begin{eqnarray*}
w= \frac{1+z}{1-z}
\end{eqnarray*}
permutes the regions the diagram below with the permutation $(1234)(5678)$.

[image]